# Как разместить пост в группе Yammer с помощью REST api json, поставив в копию пользователя?

Tags: javascript, json, rest

Есть код, который отправляет сообщение в группу:

```
   function yamPostRequest(val) {
       var msg_value = document.getElementById('msg_body').value;
       var groupID = document.getElementById('group_id').value;
       if (msg_value == "") {
           alert("Message body cannot be empty!");
           return false;
       }
       if (groupID == "") {
           var conf = confirm("Group ID is empty, message will be posted to All Company");
           if (conf == false) {
               return false;
           }
       }
       yam.platform.request({
           url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json",
           method: "POST",
           data: {
               "body": msg_value,
               //"title" : msg_title,
               "group_id": groupID,
           },
           success: function(msg) {
               alert("Post was Successful!");
           },
           error: function(msg) {
               alert("Post was Unsuccessful");
           }
       })
   }
```

он отлично отрабатывает, не могу найти в документации, как при отправки сообщения в группу, поставить пользователя в копию. Вот так:

[image: Публикация сообщения в Яммер группе, пользователь в копии]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ,

```
function PostYammerWithNotification(group_id, message, userCC) {

    var yammerData;
    yammerData = {
        group_id: group_id,
        body: message
    };
    yammerData.cc = "[[user:" + userCC + "]]";

    yam.platform.request({
        url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json",
        method: "POST",
        data: yammerData,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("Post was Successful!");
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            alert("Post was Unsuccessful");
        }
    });
}
```

Указываешь ID пользователя:

```
PostYammerWithNotification(/*ID группы*/,"test msg",/*ID пользователя*/)
```

Нашел [здеся](https://wpoffice365.com/yammer-api-sharepoint-2013/)